# When adding text() to my XPath, the number of results are duplicated. Why?

Tags: xpath

The following Xpath executed in Chrome's web inspector returns the expected number, 13, of nodes

```
//*[@id="day1"]//span[contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]
```

However, when I add text() to it:

```
//*[@id="day1"]//span[contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]/text()
```

it returns 26 nodes. However, only every other hit actually points somewhere in the source code, the others are just "numb".

The end node looks like this

```
<span class="medium bold day-time-clock">
            09:00
            <div class="tooltip-box first-free-tip ">
                <div class="tooltip-box-inner">
                    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                    Some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
```

The code sample above doesn't show exactly how it looks in the web inspector, there are a couple of empty rows in the text of this node. Here is a small screenshot of how it really looks.

[image]

Why is this happening? And what can I do about it?

Comment: What if to use `//*[@id="day1"]//span[contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]/text()[normalize-space()]`?

Comment: @JaSON That seems to have fixed it :-) Do you know why? Does text() return a new value for each row, even if they belong to the same element (is within the same quotation marks) or something like that?

Comment: I guess that your initial XPath returns 2 text nodes as empty string (the one after `</div>`) is also a spans' child text node. You can use `//*[@id="day1"]//span[contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]/text()[1]` to select required nodes only

Answer (score 1):

Your span elements have multiple text node children. Some of the text node children contain only whitespace. In your example, the outer span element has one text node child containing "....09:00...." where "...." represents whitespace, plus one text node child immediately following the child `div` element. (Incidentally, my HTML is rusty, but I didn't think that having a div inside a span was allowed.)

Your second (inner) span element contains no text nodes, so `/text()` on this should select nothing.

Generally, using `/text()` in XPath is a bad idea unless you have some very good reason and know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Do you know how I avoid matching the second inner span with my XPath? Thank you.

Comment: @michealkay No, it doesn't. At least not if I combine it with `text()`.